# increasing security in an ASP.NET automation web site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, automation

I've created a medium-sized web-based automation project for a university (VS2010,C#,ASP.NET,SQL Server 2008), now they have asked me to give some proposals in order to increase site security, what can I tell them? what are my options? encrypting the data? changing the passwords periodically? what else can I do? of course I know security is not a couple of codes that can simply be added to a huge program, but I'm searching for general approaches that can be pursued in order to increase security, any suggestion would be highly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good set of [articles](http://www.troyhunt.com/search/label/OWASP) that you may want to take a look at that may start you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Please also have a look into this MSDN Magazine article on ASP.NET Security: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580736.aspx.